# How to deploy CherryPy on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, flask, cherrypy, pythonanywhere

I have a python app developed on Flask. Everything works fine offline, I tried deploying on CherryPy successfully too. Now, I'm trying to deploy the same on www.pythonanywhere.com.

Here's the deploy.py I use for deploying the Flask app on CherryPy

```
from cherrypy import wsgiserver
from appname import app

def initiate():
    app_list = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/appname': app})
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer( ('http://username.pythonanywhere.com/'), app_list)
    try:
        server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()

print "Server initiated..."
initiate()
print "Ended"
```

I created a "manual configuration" app on pythonanywhere.com.
Here's the configuration file (username_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py):

```
import sys

path = '/home/username/appname'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

import deploy

deploy.initiate()
```

Now I'm pretty sure that it "almost worked", because in the server logs I could see my "Server initiated..." message.

```
2013-09-27 09:57:16 +0000 username.pythonanywhere.com - *** Operational MODE: single process ***
Server initiated...
```

Now the problem, when I try to view my app username.pyhtonanywhere.com/about, it times out.
This I believe is caused due to incorrect port given while starting the CherryPy server (in deploy.py).

Could anyone please tell how I can properly initiate the CherryPy server?

Comment: If you are deplyoing as WSGI you do not run the WSGIServer. You simply expose a WSGI callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joe Doherty is right. You want something more like this in you wsgi file:

```
import sys
sys.path = [ <path to your web app> ] + sys.path
from cherrypy._cpwsgi import CPWSGIApp
from cherrypy._cptree import Application

from <your_web_app> import <your web app class> 
config_path = '<path to your cherrypy config>'
application = CPWSGIApp(
    Application(<your web app class>(), '', config = config_path)
```

I stuck everything that should be based on your particular app in <>s.